# Correr aplicación Spring desde Netbeans

Tags: netbeans, spring, maven

Tengo una aplicación en Spring, al correrla con:

```
mvn spring-boot:run
```

todo funciona correctamente, pero al abrirla con Netbeans y darle run, todo parece ir bien, pero despues de aparecer el mensaje:

```
BUILD SUCCESS
```

No sucede nada, y no se activa el puerto 8080

¿Cuál es la manera correcta de correr la aplicación desde está ide?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes intentar hacer clic derecho sobre el proyecto, selecciona `Properties -> Build -> Actions`, modifica el campo "**Execute Goals**":

*org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:**{version}**:run*

Por ejemplo:

`org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.3.2.RELEASE:run`

Cuando presiones **`F6`**, la aplicación será deployada en el tomcat embebido.